# Interfaces not created after upgrade 13.04 to 14.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, kvm-virtualization

I just upgraded my server used for KVM from 13.04 to 14.04 (with 13.10 in between).

Afterwards, the various sub interfaces and bridge interfaces are missing.  The configuration is still present in /etc/network/interfaces.

I tried restarting networking, and rebooting, with no help.  Any suggestions?

Update, here is an excerpt showing bridge and sub interface configuration:

```
# Connection to MTG-C0901 gig0/2/0/19
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual


#subinterface for vlan821
auto eth1.821
iface eth1.821 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth1

#subinterface for vlan822
auto eth1.822
iface eth1.822 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth1

#vlan 821
auto br821
iface br821 inet static
bridge_ports eth1.821
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0

#vlan 822
auto br822
iface br822 inet static
bridge_ports eth1.822
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

I also noticed during boot, I see the message "Booting system without full network configuration"

Comment: What sub interfaces? Can you give examples?

Comment: See updated post with config

Answer (score -1):

Got it working after running

```
sudo apt-get install vlan
```